# jQuery tablesorter.com german numbers (300 ; 1.300 ; 13.000 ; 130.000 ; ...)

Tags: jquery, sorting, numbers, tablesorter

How to sort german numbers with jQuery tablesorter ???

{ sorter: 'ipAddress' } does not work longer in the newest version !

```
3
300
1.300
13.000
130.000 
1.300.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the "usNumberFormat" to false in your tablesorter settings. 
More info here: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/

Comment: $("#myTable").tablesorter({ widgets : ['zebra'], usNumberFormat : false, sortList: [[3,0]], headers: { 4: {sorter: false}, 5: {sorter: false}  } });